# How to make 2 components that are on different slots on the same theme layout communicate with each other

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-community

I have 1 lightning community page. In there is a theme layout component. It's just a basic layout wherein the upper 1/4 contains a logo banner and some anchor tags for navigation. Then the lower 3/4 of the layout contains the body. The body contains 1 component for my single page application. To summarize what I currently have:

```
Lightning community page
| -- Theme Layout
     | -- Upper portion of theme layout
     |    | -- c:banner
     |    | -- c:navbar
     | -- Lower portion of theme layout
          | -- c:spa
```

My problem now is, the `c:navbar` component works if it will be used for redirecting to other lightning community pages. But how will I make it send a message to the `c:spa` component so that `c:spa` can react accordingly?

One of the workarounds I made is to `navigateToURL` to the same page and just add parameters to the url every time a link in `c:navbar` is clicked, then i'll just let `c:spa` process the contents of the URL to know if there is something for it to do. However, doing this refreshes the page and loses the look and feel of a SPA. It also clutters the URL with unnecessary parameters.

Is there any way to send a message from one component to another if they are on separate slots inside a theme layout?

Comment: You can use an Application Event to communicate between the two, or you can use `aura:locationChange` to react to changes, and by the way, if you're trying to get a SPA behavior, you should be changing the location's hash (e.g. nagivateToURL using something like `#myparam=123`), which won't cause a full reload.

Comment: @sfdcfox Your comment came in as I posted the answer :) I have extensively used this kind of approach in SPAs with application events. Good to know about aura:locationChange.

Comment: I was using app events before. But using it for this case didn't cross my mind because I thought different slots in a theme layout will block the message from reaching the other component. Thank you @JayantDas that certainly is what I was looking for.

@.sfdcfox that's an approach I will definitely try. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need here is an application event. Application events by definition states:

> Application events follow a traditional publish-subscribe model. An application event is fired from an instance of a component. All components that provide a handler for the event are notified.

In your scenario, you will need to register an application event and fire it from `c:navbar` and handle that event in your `c:spa` component.

You can look for more details on communicating with events on the [help documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application.htm).